# bootstrap carousel ID and class issues

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

So I am working on implementing multiple image carousels using the bootstrap framework into my site and am having issues with implementing carousel classes. I know the issue has something to do with an existing carousel ID and it not being a class element that I can re-use multiple times, but I can not seem to find the source of where this ID is coming from to re-name it/create a class instead of an ID so I can use this carousel multiple times. I am able to create sub-class styles for the carousel but can not figure out how to re-name or re-create the #carousel-example-generic ID so I can use the carousel framework multiple times. Maybe I am just overlooking something simple...?

Thank you very much in advance for any help or direction!

```
HTML:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <title>Dan Druffel Inc. - Cincinnati Landscaping</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap Core CSS - Uses Bootswatch Flatly Theme: http://bootswatch.com/flatly/ -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom CSS -->
    <link href="css/freelancer.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/simple-sidebar.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/jquery-mobile.css" rel="stylesheet">


    <!-- Just include this Css file --> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.carousel.fullscreen.css" />


    <!-- Custom Fonts -->
    <link href="font-awesome-4.1.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,700" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,700,400italic,700italic" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

    <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://arrow.scrolltotop.com/arrow13.js"></script>
<noscript>Not seeing a <a href="http://www.scrolltotop.com/">Scroll to Top Button</a>? Go to our FAQ page for more info.</noscript>

</head>

<!-- Portfolio Modals -->
    <div class="portfolio-modal modal fade" id="portfolioModal1" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="close-modal" data-dismiss="modal">
                <div class="lr">
                    <div class="rl">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>


    <!-- This is a typical Twitter Bootstrap Carousel -->
    <!-- Carousel -->
    <div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
        <!-- Indicators -->
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
            <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
            <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
            <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2"></li>
            <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="3"></li>
            <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="4"></li>
            <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="5"></li>
            <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="6"></li>
            <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="7"></li>
            <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="8"></li>
            <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="9"></li>
            <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="10"></li>
            <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="11"></li>
            <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="12"></li>
            <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="13"></li>
        </ol>

        <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
<h1>Wood REsidence</h1>
        <center><div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="item active">
                <img src="./img/project-pics/featured_projects/Wood/Wood_img21-smaller.jpg" alt="" />
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="carousel-caption">

                        <p class="lead">Just turns the Twitter Bootstrap Carousel in fullscreen mode, and scale to fit the screen resolution</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="item">
                <img src="./img/project-pics/featured_projects/Wood/Wood_before-after.jpg" alt="" />
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="carousel-caption">

                        <p class="lead">Just turns the Twitter Bootstrap Carousel in fullscreen mode, and scale to fit the screen resolution</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="item">
                <img src="./img/project-pics/featured_projects/Wood/Wood_img5-1.jpg" alt="" />
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="carousel-caption">

                        <p class="lead">Just turns the Twitter Bootstrap Carousel in fullscreen mode, and scale to fit the screen resolution</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="item">
                <img src="./img/project-pics/featured_projects/Wood/Wood_img19-1.jpg" alt="" />
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="carousel-caption">

                        <p class="lead">Spa at dusk...</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="item">
                <img src="./img/project-pics/featured_projects/Wood/Wood_img7-before-1.jpg" alt="" />
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="carousel-caption">

                        <p class="lead">Retaining Wall - BEFORE</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="item">
                <img src="./img/project-pics/featured_projects/Wood/Wood_img8-1.jpg" alt="" />
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="carousel-caption">

                        <p class="lead">Retaining Wall - AFTER</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>


            <div class="item">
                <img src="./img/project-pics/featured_projects/Wood/Wood_img14-construction-1.jpg" alt="" />
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="carousel-caption">

                        <p class="lead">Retaining Wall - AFTER</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>


            <div class="item">
                <img src="./img/project-pics/featured_projects/Wood/Wood_img24-construction-1.jpg" alt="" />
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="carousel-caption">

                        <p class="lead">Retaining Wall - AFTER</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="item">
                <img src="./img/project-pics/featured_projects/Wood/Wood_img3-1.jpg" alt="" />
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="carousel-caption">

                        <p class="lead">Retaining Wall - AFTER</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="item">
                <img src="./img/project-pics/featured_projects/Wood/Wood_img27-1.jpg" alt="" />
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="carousel-caption">

                        <p class="lead">Retaining Wall - AFTER</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="item">
                <img src="./img/project-pics/featured_projects/Wood/Wood_img20-1.jpg" alt="" />
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="carousel-caption">

                        <p class="lead">Retaining Wall - AFTER</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="item">
                <img src="./img/project-pics/featured_projects/Wood/Wood_img23-1.jpg" alt="" />
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="carousel-caption">

                        <p class="lead">Retaining Wall - AFTER</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="item">
                <img src="./img/project-pics/featured_projects/Wood/Wood_img11-1.jpg" alt="" />
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="carousel-caption">

                        <p class="lead">Retaining Wall - AFTER</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="item">
                <img src="./img/project-pics/featured_projects/Wood/Wood_img22-1.jpg" alt="" />
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="carousel-caption">

                        <p class="lead">Retaining Wall - AFTER</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Controls -->
        <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide="prev">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
        </a>
        <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide="next">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
        </a>
    </div>


        </div>
    </div>



/* ------------------ MY Custom Carousel CSS ---------------------- */
@media (max-width: 960px) {
    body {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }
}


h1 {
color:#003300;
}

.carousel {
    padding:5%;
    position:none;
}


.carousel-inner {
    margin-top:2%;
    width:900px;
}


.item {
height: 650px;
width: 900px;
}

.carousel-caption {
position: absolute;
left: 15%;
right: 15%;
bottom: 20px;
z-index: 10;
margin-top: 50%;
padding-bottom: 20px;
color: #ffffff;
text-align: center;
text-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
}

p {
  color:#c0c0c0;
}



/* ------------------ tablet/medium screen CSS ---------------------- */

@media (min-width: 601px) and (max-width: 959px) {
.carousel-inner {
    margin-top:40%;

}

p {
  color:#ffffff;
}

.carousel-inner {
    margin-top:2%;
    width:100%;

}


.item {
height: 650px;
width: 100%;
}

.carousel-caption {
position: absolute;
left: 15%;
right: 15%;
bottom: 20px;
z-index: 10;
margin-top: 50%;
padding-bottom: 20px;
color: #ffffff;
text-align: center;
text-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
}


}


/* ------------------ phone/small screen CSS ---------------------- */
@media (min-width: 300px) and (max-width: 600px) {

h1 {
padding-top:20%;
}


p {
  color:#ffffff;
}

.carousel-caption {
position: absolute;
left: 15%;
right: 15%;
bottom: 20px;
z-index: 10;
margin-top: 0%;
padding-bottom: 100%;
color: #ffffff;
text-align: center;
text-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
}

.carousel-inner {
    margin-top:10%;
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
}


.item {
height: 700px;
width: 100%;
}


}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 <!-- Carousel -->
    <div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">


<!-- Indicators -->
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
            <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
            <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
            <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2"></li>
            <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="3"></li>
            <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="4"></li>
            <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="5"></li>
            <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="6"></li>
            <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="7"></li>
            <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="8"></li>
            <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="9"></li>
            <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="10"></li>
            <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="11"></li>
            <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="12"></li>
            <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="13"></li>
        </ol>
```

There's where it's coming from. It's also used here:

```
 <!-- Controls -->
        <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide="prev">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
        </a>
        <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide="next">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
        </a>
```

Each carousel needs a unique ID and the controls need the ID updated to match.

Comment: ok, thank you! Makes sense. So the carousel is getting called from a data-target and href correct?...so how and where would I go about creating/editing carousel IDs? (since the #carousel-example-generic is not in a CSS file...)

Comment: It uses the classes for styling. The ID is for data target and carousel controls.

Comment: ok, so I would just create the unique ID's for each carousel in the HTML document and the classes in the style sheet? For example, I would have:                                        <div id="carousel-example-generic"...> style classes ....   
<div id="carousel2-example-generic"...>                      style classes...                                                   <div id="carousel3-example-generic"...> etc...and then the data-targets would change for each carousel#...

Comment: If you have many carousels and they all look the same. Use the class="portfolio-carousel" and the id="UNIQUE-ID" (every carousel ID is unique, but the class doesn't have to be. And when you use your next and previous and the pagination (dots) those have to marry with the unique id. But when you call it with javascript, if the setting are the same, you can use the class.

Comment: Bootstrap uses the classes. The ID's are just for reuse purposes. I like to use LESS to make updating multiple carousels with different styles faster. If each needed to be uniquely styled, use the ID.

Comment: Ok, thanks for all the feedback. All the carousels are to by styled the same (but different text). So just to make sure I am understanding this correctly, I could make the carousel into this:                                                        <div class="portfolio-carousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel"> and change the controls to: <a class="left carousel-control" href=".portfolio-carousel" data-slide="prev">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
        </a>

Comment: No. You need unique ID's for each carousel unless you don't care if the controls control ALL of them simultaneously. You can't have two class declarations in HTML.

Comment: ok got it! I just defined the carousels as various #carousels in my CSS sheet and referenced each into the html doc...